# KeyCloak login with Google in Flutter/Android app

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openconnect

I am working on a Flutter app, which uses KeyCloak for Authorization in the backend. Login with username and password is implemented. I want to implement login with Google. Do anyone know, which KeyCloak endpoint and parameters are used for Google/Facebook/etc login? By the way, I have already added google in my KeyCloak configuration, and I have also set up the app on Google console. Client id, client secret are also added.

Comment: Can you give some more details? You already have your Flutter app talking to KC? Using OIDC? With PKCE? Now you've added Google as an IP in your KC realm? What stops working?

Comment: In the Flutter app, login with user name and password is already working on the KeyCloak server. Now, I want to add Login with Google (using KeyCloalk). I have added Google as an Identity provider in the KC, which is working fine as 'Login with Google' on KeyCloak's web interface. But the question is: I want this feature on my Flutter/Android app. In the Flutter app, what should the 'Login with Google' button do, when the user clicks on it? Which endpoint I should call from my app's HTTP client? which parameters/ attributes do I need to pass in HTTP requests?

Comment: Isn't the 'Login with google' button rendered by the KC login page? And you are showing that page as part of your PKCE flow? (Or are you using implicit flow?) So, doesn't KC handle the fowarding to google for you and in the end you just get the redirect back at the end of the flow? What flows do you have enabled in your KC console for the relevant client? Are you using a client to talk to KC in Flutter, or did you make your own?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my issue using this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client

This plugin opens the KeyCloak's user authentication webpage in the webview/browser. Once, the user finishes login or signup, the webview/browser returns the user credentials including the access token to the app, which is useful for making API requests e.g. to fetch user profile, etc.